Is there any other way to load the Google API in Jina Django HTML template?
So I set up a sign in with Google on Google Cloud, but I haven't implemented its logic in the backend. Do I need to implement logic in the backend to see the Google sign in widget? Because I cannot see it, I'm sure it create a client ID, I haven't set anything in settings, yes, or anything, so maybe I have to?
I'm trying to make the Google sign in the widget display, but I'm not seeing it.
Here is my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .container {
            background-color: white;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            text-align: center;
        }

        img {
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            object-fit: cover;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        p {
            color: #333;
            margin: 10px 0;
        }

        a {
            color: #007bff;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        .g_id_signin {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    {% if request.session.user_data %}
    <div>
        <p>Hi {{ request.session.user_data.given_name }} </p>
        <p>Your email is {{ request.session.user_data.email }}</p>
        <img src="{{ request.session.user_data.picture }}" alt="User picture">
        <p>Click here to <a href="/sign-out">Sign out</a></p>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div>
        <p>Hi there  </p>
        <p>Click below to sign in with Google</p>
        <div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="19752809892-j7huusq8tk032j615v78bij46fej8gs6.apps.googleusercontent.com"
     data-context="signin"
     data-ux_mode="redirect"
     data-login_uri="http://127.0.0.1:8000/google-auth-reciever"
     data-itp_support="true">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-theme="filled_blue"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>

</body>
</html>


btw i used the sign in with google widget html generator to generate the html

Yes, you need to implement te logic otherwise jinja functions will fail, try enabling Django debug mode for further details here is some information in that regard
https://learntube.ai/blog/programming/django/debugging-django-applications-tips-and-tricks/#:~:text=You%20can%20enable%20debug%20mode,in%20your%20project's%20settings%20file.&text=Django%20provides%20a%20built%2Din,in%20your%20application%20at%20runtime.
